# An event system - like signal / slot in Qt without forking - C++

Tags: c++, qt, fork, design-principles

I would like to know how to design a system that can offer a solid framework to handle signals and the connection between the signal/s and the method/s without writing a really unpleasant cycle that iterates over and over with some statement for forking the flow of the application.

In other words I would like to know the theory behind the signal slot mechanism of Qt or similar.

I'm naming Qt for no particular reason, it's just probably one of the most used and well tested library for this so it's a reference in the C++ world, but any idea about the design of this mechanism will be good.

Thanks.

Comment: in Qt this cycle does exist, it is just hidden from the user.

Comment: Take a look at the [Boost signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library.

Comment: Signal/slots don't really need an event loop. "direct" signal/slots connections in Qt (the default, unless you connect across threads) don't. Most signals/slot connections in Qt are just function calls with an intermediate tracking the connections and forwarding the signal function call to the slots.

Comment: @UmNyobe I'm aware of that, it's the first dummy solution that i have conceived, I would like to know about a more clean a productive solution, also in QT there is the moc compiler that does something that is often hidden to the user and I would like to provide what the QT library and moc provide all at once in a normal C++ application without using moc and only with a common C++ compiler toolchain.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld see my previous comment

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks but I already know about the boost libs, I already have more than 1 solution if I would like to provide signal/slot functionality in my application in the future; my point is: keys being pressed, touch events, an object that changes its own state, what is the common thing among this concepts from a programmer standpoint ? what is the theory behind this and how to write a system for handling signals and slots from the scratch without the moc compiler from QT only using a standard C++ toolchain ?

Comment: @user1797612 Boost.Signals2 is header-only and doesn't require a moc-compiler or other additional tools.

Comment: @scai my point is that i need the know-how behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, Qt's signal/slots and boost's signal library work like the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (they just avoid needing an Observer base class).

Each "signal" keeps track of what "slots" are observing it, and then iterates over all of them when the signal is emitted.

As for how to specifically implement this, the C++ is pretty similar to the Java code in the Wikipedia article. If you want to avoid using an interface for all observers, boost uses templates and Qt uses macros and a special pre-compiler (called moc).

Comment: basically no "middle-man" and the the action is triggered by a check on the assignment for a new value and handled by each "signal class" ? What i have left is: there is a particular data structure for this ? I mean how the signal class organize this ?

Comment: Yes, the signal class needs to have some way to know when to signal the observers. If the signal is for when a value changes, then the class needs to keep track of that itself; C++ does not have a way to "watch" a variable for changes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for everything but without any losses.

There are a few general concepts that I am aware of for handling asynchronous input and changes such as "keys being pressed" and "touch events" and "an object that changes its own state".

Most of these concepts and mechanisms are useful for all sorts of program flow and can cross lots of boundaries: process, thread, etc.  This isn't the most exhaustive list but they cover many of the ones I've come across.

- State Machines
- Threads
- Messages
- Event Loops
- Signals and Slots
- Polling
- Timers
- Call Back Functions
- Hooking Input
- Pipes
- Sockets

I would recommend researching these in Wikipedia or in the Qt Documentation or in a C++ book and see what works or what mechanism you want to work into your framework.

Another really good idea is to look at how programming architects have done it in the past, such as in the source of Linux or how the Windows API lets you access this kind of information in their frameworks.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Response to comment/additions to the question

I would manage a buffer/queue of incoming coordinates, and have an accessor for the latest coordinate.  Then I would keep track of events such as the start of a touch/tap/drag and the end of one, and have some sort of timer for when a long touch is performed, and a minimum change measurement for when a dragged touch is performed.

If I am using this with just one program, I would try to make a interface that is similar to what I could find in use.  I've heard of OpenSoundControl being used for this kind of input.  I've set up a thread that collects the coordinates and keeps track of the events.  Then I poll for that information in the program/class that needs to use it.

Comment: Ok, I propose a more specific question: I have an hardware sensor and a timer, i have no problem in reading the data from the sensor, for example the coordinates of a touch, now how I can build a signal slot system where the signal is a change in coordinates and the slot is a generic method or methods ? How to manage a queque ?

Comment: ok, but your answer is really generic, i woul like to read something much more related to C++, for example in C++ there is a data structure that can notify me when the values of its own members changes ? Your answer is a good start for what i'm looking for but it's more like an algorithmic approach rather an approach for the real programming phase or for the C++ . I hope that now it's clear where my question is pointing.

Comment: There isn't a data structure that does this out of the box.  Using signal and slots you can create classes that do this.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

The implementation details of the mocc'ed can be seen in the moc_XXX.cpp files that get generated by qmake.